# Differences between Slope of budget line and MRS?

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory

Slope of budget line= change in y/ change in x and also  Marginal rate of substitution= change in y/ change in x. If the definitions are same of both then what is the difference between the two? I mean 1. Slope of the budget line will be number of units of good y that the consumer is willing to sacrifice for an additional unit of good x. 2. The marginal rate of substitution (MRS) is the amount of a good that a consumer is willing to give up for another good. Here both definitions means the same, right?

Comment: Your "definitions" are not very precise.

Comment: Now, are they precise?

Answer (score 7):

Not really, you're right in that (loosely speaking) the MRS is the amount of one good someone **is willing** to give up in order to get an additional unit of another good. However, the slope of the budget line measures the amount of one good someone **has** to give up in order to get an additional unit of another good.

In the first case, only *preferences* matter, whereas in the second only *prices* are relevant.